# Get Skype extension for Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, skype, google-chrome-extensions

How do you get the Skype extension on Google Chrome?

For some reason it's not in the Chrome Web Store.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[**Skype’s Click and Call plug-in**](http://www.skype.com/intl/en/get-skype/on-your-computer/click-and-call/) for Google Chrome can be downloaded from Skype's website.

Answer (score 2):

You can download the Skype Developer Toolbar from Skype's website too.

Answer (score 1):

I came here looking for the same answer, and after coming up disappointed, I made one that served my needs: http://ishiboo.com/SkypeControl/

I only made it work on Windows however. Hope it helps!